# my app got rejects [default handler not found]

Tags: android, google-play-console

After review, we found that your app does not qualify for use of the requested permissions. In your permissions declaration form, you had indicated that your app is a default handler; however, we were unable to detect that capability in your app’s manifest.

i had developed a app which can help in emergency so am using below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

i am using call_phone to call directly 100 and other emergency numbers
and send_sms to send direct sms to particular contacts.

while publishing they asked me core functionality
i had tick
default sms
default phone  ..  tick on first version

second version i have tick 
deafaut sms
default phone
safety alert- emergency senior

both the time it got rejects saying same message.

please help me how to overcome rejection again and again

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell what you entered wrongfully - while a) not knowing what you've entered there (especially permissions `SEND_SMS` and `CALL_PHONE` might be problematic), as well as not having seen the app. an app not being a default handler generally means, that there might be an `intent-filter` missing in the `Manifest.xml`, which would enable it to be selected as the default handler for one or several intents. if you don't have one, you need to correct the submission form.

See this [article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html) on the Android Developers blog, which explains the permission problem you're facing.

The issue with old people is, that they barely can handle a smartphone - especially in case of emergency.  there are phones with huge buttons, which have an additional `ICE` button in the back, which does just that - and while still remembering the button, this is far more reliable than having to unlock a smartphone. `ICE` means in case of emergency ...demanding technical understanding in such a situation, that can indeed be life threatening; just consider a stoke - which phone do you think is more likely to provide emergency services on time?

On Android, I'd rather suggest to set up the system default "ICE Information", if there are any medical conditions, which first-responders should be aware of, alike: medications, allergies, etc. This information is accessible without having to unlock the phone; just alike emergency calls.

Comment: i am not getting you properly, can you tell me where am i wrong exactly @ martin

Comment: @HarjinderSinghBobby would assume that you're not matching the requirements for providing an `ICE` application (or no proper reason why it has to send SMS). `ICE` is a thing about life and death, which by the way is being supported by default - what if someone fails to use it in case of emergency, will you stand responsible for the consequences? hard to imagine you would qualify as a suitable vendor, when not even grasping such a basic explanation, which does provide the relevant blog post to read.